# В чем проблема синтаксиса Declare?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Вечер добрый, в чем проблема синтаксиса?

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @sum money, @id int, @prodid int, @name nvarchar(20)' at line 1    0.000 sec

```
use sakila;
DECLARE @sum money, @id int, @prodid int, @name nvarchar(20);
SET @id = 2;

select @sum = sum(Orders.Price*Orders.ProductCount),
    @name = Products.ProductName, @prodid = Products.Id
from orders
inner join Products on ProductId = Products.Id
group by Products.ProductName, Products.Id
having Products.Id = @id

PRINT 'Товар ' + @name + 'продан на сумму '+str(@sum)
```

Comment: 1) Вам же написано - "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version" - каков результат проверки? 2) "Синтаксиса", а не "синтакса". Я аж в словарь полез проверять. Отредактировал текст.

Comment: declare можно использовать только внутри блоков процедурного кода, а не в sql. И для объявления процедурных переменных, которые без собак. А те что с собаками, предназначенные для использования в sql, объявлять вообще не нужно и тип указывать не нужно, а сразу устанавливать начальные значения.

Comment: Пытаться выполнить SQL-код, специфичный для SQL Server, в Workbench на MySQL - это мазохизм какой-то...